# Display content of JSON response using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I'm very new to Knockout, and indeed Javascript, so I have no doubt my question is stupid. But I find the documentation of KnockoutJS to assume you know already a lot about Javascript so the examples are not complete enough for me.

I have a REST API that returns JSON data, like this:

```
{"$id":"1","$values":
    [
        {"$id":"2",
            "id":14,
            "name":"Bound to pretend",
            "artist":
                {"$id":"3",
                "id":12,
                "name":"Velvet Veins"
                }},
        {"$id":"4",
        "id":13,
        "name":"This Is It",
        "artist":
            {"$id":"5",
                "id":11,
                "name":"Michael Jackson"
            }}
    ]
}
```

So the response is an array of `ShortAlbumDto` objects, one of the property being another object of the `Artist` type.

I'm trying to use KnockoutJS to display this data in a table. Here's the HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: albums">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: artist.name"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my KnockoutJS component (which is used in the Home one) is this:

albums-latest.js:

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./albums-latest.html'], function(ko, templateMarkup) {
    function AlbumsLatest(params) {

        var self = this;
        self.albums = ko.observableArray([]);

        $.getJSON('http://localhost:62755/api/album/latest', self.albums)
  }

  // This runs when the component is torn down. Put here any logic necessary to clean up,
  // for example cancelling setTimeouts or disposing Knockout subscriptions/computeds.
  AlbumsLatest.prototype.dispose = function() { };

  return { viewModel: AlbumsLatest, template: templateMarkup };

});
```

home.html:

```
<h2>Home</h2>

<albums-latest></albums-latest>
```

albums-latest is properly registered in startup.js:

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', './router', 'bootstrap', 'knockout-projections'], function($, ko, router) {

  // Components can be packaged as AMD modules, such as the following:
  ko.components.register('nav-bar', { require: 'components/nav-bar/nav-bar' });
  ko.components.register('home-page', { require: 'components/home-page/home' });

  // ... or for template-only components, you can just point to a .html file directly:
  ko.components.register('about-page', {
    template: { require: 'text!components/about-page/about.html' }
  });

  ko.components.register('albums-latest', { require: 'components/albums-latest/albums-latest' });

  // [Scaffolded component registrations will be inserted here. To retain this feature, don't remove this comment.]

  // Start the application
  ko.applyBindings({ route: router.currentRoute });
});
```

(I used yeoman for scaffolding and adding the component).

My problem is that when I execute this, Firebug tells me that `artist is not referenced`. CORS is enabled and I can see the Ajax request firing and the WebApi returning the data just find - I just can't seem to map it in a way that Knockout understands.

Comment: For starters, your API is returning XML, not JSON.  You either need to get it to return JSON, or parse it as XML.

Comment: You're saying the rest API is returning JSON data, but you posted XML data.  Can you log the value that's being returned by the ajax request (`$.getJSON('http://localhost:62755/api/album/latest', function(r) { console.log(r); self.albums(r); })`)?

Comment: Woops, sorry for the wrong example. I've reached the API with the browser and that defaults to XML, but when done through the code it *is* JSON - I will update the question.

Comment: Value returned with the above code is: Object { $id: "1", $values: Array[14] }

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON data by either looking at the Network tab within Firebug and look for the ajax request being made or use the following code `console.log(JSON.stringify(r));`?

Comment: I updated the question with the correct output, is it good for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:62755/api/album/latest', function(r) {
    self.albums(r.$values);
});
```

In you're case the response is mapped directly to the `albums` array (since `getJSON(url, observable)` is essentially the same as `getJSON(url, function(r) { observable(r); })`), but the ajax request is returning an object where the `$values` property contains the actual albums array.

Comment: This works. For my understanding, what was wrong in the way I did it and why does your code work?